# Adding virtual processor to hyper-v windows 7 32 bit image makes it not boot

Tags: hyper-v

I installed a Windows 7 professional 32 bit guest on a windows 8.1 hyper-v image. When I go to the settings and change the virtual processor count from 1 to 2 it no longer boots. Unless, I first use msconfig to limit it to using one processor. However, as soon as I remove that contstraint it again fails to boot.

My question to the gurus out there in serverfault land is how can I get my windows 7 guest to boot with 2 virtual processors. This is a build machine with complex software that takes days to put together so I am really looking to not have to reinstall just to add another virtual processor.

Comment: Sounds like you're in dire need of a configuration management system.

Comment: I don't know what that is, but it sounds horrible if you need a 'configuration  management system' to add a vCPU.

Comment: I assume your actually processor has HT support and has more then a single core?

Comment: My processor is a Core i7-2860QM CPU @ 2.5 GHz.

Comment: I have verified that a new installation from the exact same installation media works with 4 virtual CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

This may be very obvious, but I had a similar problem with a VM after I replaced the motherboard on my computer.   The new BIOS setting for Hyper-V was disabled.  When I enabled it, my problems went away.

Comment: I just checked and intel vt and intel vt direct i/o are enabled.